# How to save file downloaded by lftpget to the specified path?

Tags: java, linux, jsp, tomcat

How to save file downloaded by lftpget to the specified path?
I used Apache Tomcat to set up web server under Linux, in JSP page I try to invoke lftpget or curl to download big file

from FTP server, it works. But the downloaded file is save in ../apache-tomcat-7.0.37/bin, how do I save the download file

to the local path?
The code I have tried:

```
    <body>
    <%
    String cmddown = "lftpget ftp://" + host + remoteFile + " -P " + storepath;
    Process p_down = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmddown);
    p_down.waitFor();
    %>
    </body> 
or
    <body>
    <%
    String cmddown = "curl -O ftp://" + host + remoteFile + " " + storepath;
    Process p_down = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmddown);
    p_down.waitFor();
    %>
    </body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSP is being executed on the server.  There's no way to make the PDF appear at the client without transmitting it from the server, *after* the server downloads it, or doing a redirect to the `ftp://...` URL. This would involve restructuring your code and web interaction, as you're already in the middle of sending an HTML document and can't just switch mid-stream to sending a PDF.  How to do this is probably beyond the scope of what can be taught here.